# Is it a good practice to declare class with only static members as abstract?

Tags: java, static, abstract-class

I have 2 singleton services, each of them must have a 'context' field, but this field must be represented as the same object for both singletons.
Also, access to this object must be limited by these singletons.
Further, there is a chance that I will add the third singleton service with this field, and that one must be represented with the same object too.
My first approach was smth like this:

```
abstract class Abs {
   protected static Object context = new Object();
   // some static methods
}
class Service1 extends Abs {}
class Service2 extends Abs {}
```

But I'm not sure that it is a good solution.

Comment: I see only one problem: if _context_ can be mutated from _Service1_ and _Service2_, then it will become difficult to trace issues, because – as an example – _Service1_ could mutate _context_ and trust that _context_ remains unchanged but _Service2_ could mutate it any given point of time. If _context_ resp. all its properties are immutable, then I do not see problems with your solution.

Comment: A class that only has static members isn't really a class, inheritance is usually bad, and singleton is an anti-pattern. So no, not good practice. A better approach would be a factory that instantiates the two services, and constructs each with a common context. Context can be a private instance field of each service. Much better for unit testing, because it's easy to test a service by injecting a mock/stub/fake context.

Comment: Thx for your answers

Comment: Good practice == Bad practice == opinion.

Comment: Yet another *alternative* solution is to declare the class as `final` and declare its only constructor as `private`.  That prevents creation of subclasses AND creation of (unwanted) instances.  (But it doesn't address the testability issue.)